# Why statically defined strings are stored in read-only area of memory

Tags: c

Can't resist to ask after seeing answers to my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021454/difference-between-declared-string-and-allocated-string) question.

```
char* msg = "Stack-overflow"; // Stored on read-only memory region of process.
int i=10; // Stored onto stack.
```

why `"Stack-overflow"` will be stored on read-only memory area of process and value `10` is not?

Edited to clear my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the variables are stored in read-only memory. However, the memory `msg` *points to* is read-only.

That's not enforced by the C standard though - it's simply common practice to do so. There is more information about this in the following question: [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Comment: I believe the follow-up would be why is the string `Stack-overflow` stored in read-only memory. +1 for your distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the string `"Stack-overflow"` with the `10` and the variable `msg` with the variable `i`. You are allowed to change the pointer value of `msg` and you are not allowed to change the value of `10`. If the `10` would be a bigger difficult number there is a good chance it ends up in read-only memory too.

Answer (score 0):

No variable is stored in read-only memory, msg points to read-only memory so if we try to modify it compiler will flag an error.
although we can assign msg to other address.(It behaves like pointer to constant object in c++)