# segmentation violation when indirecting through unallocated pointers

Tags: c, linux, uniq

I tried something but Resus mainly not know how to read the file line by line to compare lines between them, I get the error segmentation fault ( core dumped ).
This is my function for uniq -u command

```
void uniq_u()
{
//  strcpy(file_name1,params[2]);
FILE *file = fopen ( file_name1, "r" );
if ( file != NULL )
{

  fgets(prev, sizeof prev,file);
  while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
  {
 if(!strcmp(line, prev))

        printf("%s", prev);
 else 
        strcpy(prev,line);
  }
  fclose ( file );
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Debugging is a super method to find out where segmentation violations occur. You don't show how `prev` and `line` are defined (why not make them locals?), but my guess is that they are pointers without memory allocated to them. In other words, you probably have `char *line;` where you need `char line[200];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mention the declaration of "prev" and "line" variables.
Regardless , I think reading this might solve your problem : [Difference between char* and char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653034/the-difference-between-char-and-char)

Comment: char *line;
char *prev;

Comment: @LaurentiuBobora try reading the answers from the link I provided , char* is read-only unless dynamically allocated and you should have also got a warning about using uninitialized pointers. Changing them into char line[200] , prev[200]; should make it work.

Comment: I have changed, but not even go so :(

Comment: @LaurentiuBobora have you also changed the 2nd parameter of fgets to 199 ?

Comment: @LaurentiuBobora I'm glad you got it working. Don't forget to mark my answer as selected answer if it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I try to implement uniq -i command, you must display the contents of a file without duplicate lines 
exemple : 
I have
I have
bad
you
you 

I must display: 
I have
bad
you

This is my function


    void uniq_i()
    {
     //file_name1=fopen(params[2],"r");
   
   if ( file_name1 != NULL )
   {
      
      fgets(prev1,199,file_name1);
      while ( fgets ( line, 199, file_name1 ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
 
 if(!strcmp(prev1,line))
 {
 
  printf("%s", prev1);
  
  
 }
 else if(strcmp(prev1,line))
 {
 
  printf("%s",line);
  
  
 }
 
 strcpy(prev1,line);
      }