# Passing const char * to a C function

Tags: c, pointers, char

For the below [question](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node8.html#SECTION00840000000000000000),

> Write a function `replace` which takes a pointer to a string as a parameter, which replaces all spaces in that string by minus signs, and delivers the number of spaces it replaced.
>
> Thus
>
> ```
>    char *cat = "The cat sat";
>    n = replace( cat );
> ```
>
> should set
>
> ```
>     cat to "The-cat-sat"
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>    n to 2.
> ```

---

In the above problem, `char *cat="That cat sat"` is nothing but `const char *cat="That cat sat"`

Here is my non-working code for this problem,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int replace(char[]);
int main(void){
  const char *cat = "The cat sat";
  int n = replace((char[])cat);
  printf("\n Now the output is: \"%s\"", cat);
  printf("n is %d", n);
}

int replace(char cat[]){
  int count =0;
  for(int i =0; cat[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(cat[i] == ' ') {
      cat[i] = '-';
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

To analyse this code,

`const char *cat` is pointing to a buffer(`The cat sat`) that cannot be modified.

So, am casting(`(char[])`) to make `cat` a (non-const)modifiable buffer, before calling `replace((char[])cat)`. Because, C is loosely typed

But the program still segments at `cat[i]='-'`

How do I understand this problem?

Comment: "make `cat` a (non-const)modifiable buffer," by casting and then calling `replace()` invokes undefined behavior - it might work, it might not, .  Better to make a copy of the data pointed by `cat` in a modifiable buffer and call `replace()` on that.

Comment: @chux Might work? I want to take a call on `(char[])cat`

Comment: The exercise you were given is wrong: There is no way to change a string literal, so the exercise is impossible. They should change it to `char cat[] = "The cat sat";` to make the exercise correct.

Comment: @interjay Confirmed from you. You helped me

Comment: `char *` is not the same as `const char *` as you say in the question

Comment: Technically it is possible to meet the stipulation, with some macro trickery, but I doubt this is what was meant by the exercise

Answer (score 1):

I cover this question at great length in this question:

[Difference between declared string and allocated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021454/difference-between-declared-string-and-allocated-string/16021546#16021546).

In short, the manner in which you declare the string, regardless of the **`const` storage class modifier**, is stored in RODATA (ie: text segment), so re-casting it to non-`const` (something you should try to avoid, since there are few legitimate reasons for doing this) doesn't help you.

In [c](/questions/tagged/c), if you want to make a buffer selectively-writable, hide it away in a context variable or as a static variable within a source file, and only allow access to it via private API calls (ie: "getter"/"setter" functions).

Comment: Not sure, how do I make some `getter` private using C? In Java it is easy. What is context variable?

Comment: I'll attach an example using an opaque `struct` in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Strings inside "" are called string literals. These are immutable.
So, instead of

```
 const char *cat = "The cat sat";
```

You can write:

```
char cat[20]; // This or calloc/malloc. Your choice
strcpy(cat, "The cat sat");
```

And then pass this in to the function.

Comment: For safety reasons use strncpy (strcpy with max copy length), to avoid errors with missing „\0“ stings